# Ajax MYSQL search and sorting results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

Trying to find out how to add sort option of my mysql results that are fetched with Ajax functionality. Sorting by mysql columns or something. Below are some "th" sections where I would like to have sorting options implemented.

HTML page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Tool details</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search for tool details" class="form-control" />
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    load_data();

    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '') {
            load_data(search);
        } else {
            load_data();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please not that sorting is added only for ID column at the moment to avoid complicating code here.

fetch.php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/connect-db.php');

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tools
                WHERE toolsn LIKE '%".$search."%'
                OR toolcategory LIKE '%".$search."%'
                OR tooldesc LIKE '%".$search."%'
                OR toolpn LIKE '%".$search."%'
                OR toolstatus LIKE '%".$search."%'";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tools ORDER BY id";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
//get feedback why database not working
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
    exit();
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output .= '
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table bordered">
                <tr>
                 <th>Customer Name</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
                 <th>City</th>
                 <th>Postal Code</th>
                 <th>Country</th>
                </tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row["tooldesc"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["toolcategory"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["toolsn"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["toolpn"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["toolstatus"].'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
    echo $output;
}else {
    echo 'Data Not Found';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reproduce sorting option with below code, but this works only if I directly access fetch.php page.
When I tried to fetch details through my html page (over the script) only results are shown, but without sorting function (hyperlinks are not working)
Probably because below code cant read two strings because fetch.php is included in parent html page.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tools ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
```

so $orderby and $order are not giving command to $query because it is not directly accessed page. Script from html page is reading results from fetch.php.

fetch.php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/connect-db.php');


    $orderBy = "id";
    $order = "asc";

    if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])) {
        $orderBy = $_GET["orderby"];
    }
    if(!empty($_GET["order"])) {
        $order = $_GET["order"];
    }

    $idNextOrder = "asc";
    $tooldescNextOrder = "asc";
    $toolcategoryNextOrder = "asc";
    $toolsnNextOrder = "asc";
    $toolpnNextOrder = "asc";
    $toolstatusNextOrder = "asc";

    if($orderBy == "id" and $order == "asc") {
        $idNextOrder = "desc";
    }
    if($orderBy == "tooldesc" and $order == "asc") {
        $tooldescNextOrder = "desc";
    }
    if($orderBy == "toolcategory" and $order == "asc") {
        $toolcategoryNextOrder = "desc";
    }
    if($orderBy == "toolsn" and $order == "asc") {
        $toolsnNextOrder = "desc";
    }
    if($orderBy == "toolpn" and $order == "asc") {
        $toolpnNextOrder = "desc";
    }
    if($orderBy == "toolstatus" and $order == "asc") {
        $toolstatusNextOrder = "desc";
    }


$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tools 
  WHERE toolsn LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR toolcategory LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR tooldesc LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR toolpn LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR toolstatus LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 //$query = "SELECT * FROM tools";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tools ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;

}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
//get feedback why database not working
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
    exit();
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="id"><a title="Sort by system ID" href="?orderby=id&order='.$idNextOrder.'">ID</a></th>
        <th class="toolsn"><a title="Sort by tool serial number" href="?orderby=toolsn&order='.$toolsnNextOrder.'">Tool SN</a></th>   
        <th class="toolpn"><a title="Sort by tool part number" href="?orderby=toolpn&order='.$toolpnNextOrder.'">Tool PN</a></th>
        <th class="toolcategory"><a title="Sort by tool category" href="?orderby=toolcategory&order='.$toolcategoryNextOrder.'">Tool category</a></th>    
        <th class="tooldesc"><a title="Sort by tool description" href="?orderby=tooldesc&order='.$tooldescNextOrder.'">Tool description</a></th>      
        <th class="toolstatus"><a title="Sort by tool status" href="?orderby=toolstatus&order='.$toolstatusNextOrder.'">Tool status</a></th>
        <th class="options"></th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["toolsn"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["toolpn"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["toolcategory"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["tooldesc"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["toolstatus"].'</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```